# Index Match UserForm of multiple Textboxes

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a very simple userform that lets the user enter a name and a number then it inserts those in a certain cell and adds some specific text in between them. Each name has an associated number. For example Adams = 286.

The following code I have applies the number after you click or press enter on the first name textbox.

```
Private Sub ufSUBnum_Enter()
Dim dataNum As Variant
dataNum = Application.Index(Range("Data!$U$3:$U$679"), _
Application.Match(ufSUBname.Value, Range("Data!T3:T679"), 0), 1)

If IsError(dataNum) Then
    ufSUBnum.Value = ""
Else
    ufSUBnum.Value = dataNum
End If
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is also index match the name from the number. Sometimes we don't know the name or its just quicker to enter the number but also a lot of times we don't know the number.

I tried flipping around the ranges (including changing the userform textbox tag) so when i type in the 3 digit number it will apply the associated name.

It just comes back with error 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Guess your first `Application.Match` argument refers to a TextBox Control value, i.e. to a string by default whereas your match refers to **number formatted cells** in the search column. If so you'll have to convert your search string of the TextBox (say you named it XYcontrol)  to a number, e.g. via `Application.Match(Val(XYcontrol.value), …`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Private Sub ufSUBnum_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Dim dataNum As Variant

If ufSUBnum.Value <> "" Then
    Set FindName = Worksheets("Data1").Range("$T$3:$T679").Find(ufSUBnum.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If FindName Is Nothing Then
        ufSUBnum.Value = ""
    Else
        ufSUBnum.Value = FindName.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
End If

End Sub
```